# Very slow updates and deletes on unreferenced PostgreSQL table with low row count

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-rds

I have a PostgreSQL 13 database with a table named `cache_record`, hosted on Amazon RDS.

This is the table's definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cache_record
(
    key text NOT NULL,
    type text NOT NULL,
    value bytea NOT NULL,
    expiration timestamptz NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    updated_at timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    CONSTRAINT cache_record_pkey PRIMARY KEY (key)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX cache_record_expiration_idx
    ON cache_record USING btree
    (expiration ASC NULLS LAST);
```

The table itself is not referenced by any foreign key (so no indexing/trigger issue) and only contains ~ 30000 rows. The `value` field does not exceed 1 MB in length on each row, with less than 50 bytes for 50% of the rows. Normally, DELETEs are performed as such:

```sql
DELETE FROM cache_record 
WHERE expiration < NOW();
```

There are ~ 10000 expired rows to delete in the table. But this query takes too long to execute and the batch that runs it times out. So I decided to split it in batches and execute it manually from a shell:

```sql
DELETE FROM cache_record 
WHERE key IN (SELECT key
              FROM cache_record
              WHERE expiration < NOW()
              ORDER BY created_at
              LIMIT 100)
```

One batch of 100 rows takes ~ 30 s to execute, which is absurd. The nested SELECT itself executes a lot faster than the nesting DELETE (with or without LIMIT).

The query never caused any issue until yesterday, when the CRON batch that is supposed to purge entries from the table started to timeout (30 s). Although, it's entirely possible that the query has always been slow but was just under the timeout threshold until yesterday.

What could be causing the slowness?

---

**Edit 2023-01-20**

I ran the query using EXPLAIN as suggested in the comments:

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYSE, BUFFERS) DELETE FROM cache_record WHERE expiration < NOW();
```

I purged the table yesterday so the query only had a few hits, but it's enough to show the speed issue (> 10 s of execution time):

```
Delete on cache_record  (cost=14.28..501.73 rows=257 width=6) (actual time=10595.107..10595.109 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=200819 read=43245 dirtied=42783 written=9470
  I/O Timings: read=3037.437 write=73.217
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on cache_record  (cost=14.28..501.73 rows=257 width=6) (actual time=0.528..29.769 rows=551 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (expiration < now())
        Heap Blocks: exact=88
        Buffers: shared hit=10 read=85 dirtied=34 written=21
        I/O Timings: read=2.006 write=0.161
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on cache_record_expiration_idx  (cost=0.00..14.22 rows=257 width=0) (actual time=0.030..0.031 rows=551 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (expiration < now())
              Buffers: shared hit=7
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=56
Planning Time: 0.324 ms
Execution Time: 10595.676 ms
```

Comment: Make an exact copy of the table/data, but with no index, and run the delete. How much faster is it?

Comment: As always, please show an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, turning track_io_timing on first if possible.  Why do you have a timeout set on your cronjobs in the first place?

Comment: *I decided to split it in batches and execute it manually from a shell*, pretty much guaranteed to slow it down.

Comment: @Belayer The original query took too long to run, it was not an option for me to lock the table that long. Event if the split runs a bit slower, it was the only way I found to purge the table without locking it 30 minutes.

Comment: @jjanes I added the requested `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` query result, with `track_io_timing` on (it was actually already on, maybe an Amazon RDS specificity?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the large number of buffers read and dirtied which show up only on the DELETE node, I would say your time is going to maintaining [the TOAST table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html), deleting the huge "value" column.  I don't know why it wasn't a problem before, maybe you were naturally deleting only a few records at a time before, or maybe you were principally deleting smaller records before. You said 50% are below 50 bytes, but maybe that 50% is not evenly distributed and you just hit a big slug of large ones.

As for the speed of the select, when you only select the "key" column, it doesn't need to access the TOAST records for the "value" column, so it doesn't spend any time doing so.

Comment: That was also my conclusion. After investigating further, I noticed the previous execution times were lower than the CRON task's timeout threshold, but still very high for a simple DELETE query. I probably had a traffic peak that snowballed afterwards since the job did not delete anything anymore. I think I have to redesign my caching system, e.g. use a dedicated distributed cache like Redis.